# How to serialize only certains elements of a object?

Tags: java, android, serialization

i want to serialize this class, to store it on the sdcard of the phone, but i want to serialize all but the bitmaps, the bitmaps must be not stored and must be null when the class is loaded again from the sdcard into a object (unserialized)

How it is possible to serialize all but the bitmaps?

this is my code:

```
public class Page implements Serializable{
String src;
String id;
String thumbnail;
public ArrayList<Area> areas;   
public Bitmap pageBitmap;
public Bitmap thumbnailBitmap;
}
```

I know how to store a object on the sdcard, and i know that this object must be serializable, but when i do it, it is trying to store the bitmaps also, but i dont want that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`transient`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient) keyword:

```
public transient Bitmap pageBitmap;
```

Comment: the bitmap will be null when the class is unserialized

Comment: @AndroidUser99: Yes, which is what you write that you want.